# Integrate visit times in curl request PHP

Tags: php, curl, bots, libcurl

i want to integrate a visit time to simulate real visit times in a curl request on PHP  but i don't know how to make this.

Basically I want my curl request to stay on the page like a normal user for 30 seconds before sending the "POST" request for the site to consider that my bot curl has remained 30 seconds on the page.

I found two ways :

-`Sleep()`  : if i use sleep After curl_exec i sont know if the request will add a pause in a curl request.

-`CURL_PAUSE`  i don't found how it work and i don't know if permit me of simulate a a real visit time.
 Code exemple :

Code : 
(I've already tried search on Google how or work CURL_PAUSE but it's not good explain.

PS : Don't mind the SSL_verifypeer I know I can use a certificate it's just an example ^^)

````
$timeout = 10;

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

if (preg_match('`^https://`i', $url))
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Utilisation de la méthode POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Définition des champs et valeurs à envoyer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
'email' => 'user@domain.tld'
));

$page_content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $page_content;```
````

Comment: Please explain a bit more what you're trying to do. It's a bit unclear at the moment. You should also add any attempt you've made, or at a minimum the code you want to modify.

Comment: I gave more détail

Comment: Can no one answer my question? :(